# jQuery ajax jsonp calls error after success

Tags: json, jquery, cross-domain, jsonp

I'm using jQuery 1.9.1 performing jsonp against the Etsy API. Below is a routine used to call into the API; it accepts a signed request (url), a jsonp callback name and an error handler.

```
call: function (signedOAuthRequest, callback, errorFn) {
    $.ajax({
        url: signedOAuthRequest,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: callback,
        jsonp: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        cache: true,
        processData: false,
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if (errorFn != undefined) {
                errorFn(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        }
    });
```

Usage:

```
call("http://the.api/?signedrequest", "myCallback", myErrorHandler);
```

And it works. `myCallback` fires, the json object received looks good. Everything's fine.

Except...

Immediately after `myCallback` completes, the error handler runs. In the error handler, the status code is 200 and the error message is `"parsererror"`. errorThrown.message is `"myCallback was not called"`. Thing is, `myCallback` was *definitely* called and the json object passed to it was parsed just fine, so I don't get this at all.

Why is this error being thrown on an otherwise successful call?

Comment: move callback to `success: callback`, remove `jsonp: false`, remove `jsonpCallback`, remove `cache: true`, `type: "get"` isn't needed either. `processData` also isn't needed.

Comment: If you instead want to define your own callback on the window, don't use jsonp datatype, just use getScript.

Comment: and pass `myCallback` rather than `"myCalback"` as `callback` parameter

Comment: Are you in charge of `the.api`?  Is it the same domain of the origin of the JS ocde that is running in your example?

Comment: @KevinB The URL is a pre-baked SHA-1 signed OAuth 1.0 request (generated by the server and handed off to the JS client). It's already got the name of a callback baked into the signature, so if I let jQuery manage the name of the callback (or allow it to add a cache timestamp to the URL), this creates an OAuth signature mismatch on the provider.

Comment: @ExplosionPills I'm not in charge of the API and yea, the call is cross-domain.

Comment: Note - the round trip for data *works*. I successfully receive data from the API. There's not a problem *getting* the data or running the callback; that all works fine. When I call the API, 2 methods are being run as a result: my callback *and* my error handler run back to back for each call. Both success and failure occur. I need to eliminate the error handler being called if/when there's no apparent error. It smells like a jQuery bug, tbh. My current workaround is to ignore the error if the status is 200, but I'd much rather the error handler not run at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments and what's in your question, this is how i would write that code:

```
function (signedOAuthRequest, callbackName, successFn, errorFn) {
    $.ajax({
        url: signedOAuthRequest,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: callbackName,
        jsonp: false,
        cache: true,
        success: successFn,
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if (typeof errorFn !== 'undefined') {
                errorFn(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I made the following changes:

Added an additional parameter to pass a success callback. This is required because jQuery will define the callback for you so that it can retrieve the successful response and parse it.

Removed `crossdomain: true` because it is redundant

Removed `proccessData: false` because it doesn't affect jsonp requests and you aren't passing any data

Added `success: successFn` so that jQuery will execute `successFn` on success with the parsed json data.

Renamed callback to callbackName so that it's more obvious about what it contains.

An alternate solution if you still insist on defining the callback yourself is to use the script dataType (taken from comments below)

```
$.ajax({
    url: signedOAuthRequest,
    dataType: "script",
    cache: true
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately the addition of a success handler didn't change the behavior. As before, the callback runs and is passed a well formed json object; this is followed immediately by the error handler running. In the error handler, `jqXHR.status` is 200, `jqXHR.statusText` is "success", `textStatus` is "parsererror" and `errorThrown.message` is "fn.home.jsonp.getRecentlyConnectedEoatCallback was not called". But that function **is being called**. From what I can tell, the only error here is the fact that jQuery is throwing an error.

Comment: Stop defining the function yourself! jQuery will define it for you. Pass either an anonymous function, or a reference to a function that doesn't have the same name as the callback name you are passing.

Comment: `signedOAuthRequest` is a signed OAuth request. If you allow jQuery to munge it with additional query parameters, you'll break OAuth. This is why `cache: true` is set; it prevents jQuery from adding the `_` parameter to `signedOAuthRequest`. This is also why `jsonp: false` is set; it prevents jQuery from munging `signedOAuthRequest` with a `callback` parameter. Also, because it's ultimately required in the request URL, the `callback` parameter *must* be included in the URL *prior* to signing it.

Comment: If my assumption as to how you are actually performing this request is correct, you should be able to do this: http://pastebin.com/ZAWZ5FSH If that works, then there's absolutely no reason doing it my way wouldn't work too if called properly.

Comment: That works, and I think using "script" is the best solution for my scenario. Apparently there is no way to handle cross-domain `$.ajax` errors, at least not via ajax's error option. According to the jQuery docs, the only 2 permissible cross-domain data types are "jsonp" and "script", both of which claim to *not* call ajax error handlers by design. That being the case, "script" behaves more reliably than "jsonp" because "script" never calls the error handler, whereas "jsonp" can be coerced into calling it erroneously.

Comment: In JQ 1.9, you should be using done, fail and always... not success, error, complete.

Comment: @trgraglia but there's nothing wrong with using success error or complete. they aren't depreciated, they aren't going anywhere, syntactically they're still expressive and easy to maintain.

Comment: @KevinB Per docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

Comment: You're miss-interpreting the depreciation notice. Read it again. (note, theres a BIG difference between the options object and the jqXHR that gets returned from ajax methods).

Comment: You'll want to use `.done()`, `fail()` and `always()` functions instead